# How to execute updates in Greenplum?

Tags: greenplum

I want to execute insert, update, delete statement on an internal table in Greenplum, I wants to update data of an internal table using the external table.
my internal table DDL is

`create table test
(
"ID" bigint,
"a"  char(10),
"b"  char(10),
primary key ("a")
)DISTRIBUTED BY ("a");`

When I execute update on this table I get the error

- **ERROR**:  Cannot prallelize an UPDATE statement that updates the distribution columns*
  How I should go ahead?

Comment: You can't update the "a" column because that is how you are distributing the data.  I also recommend you remove the primary key from the table.  It isn't needed.

Comment: I am trying to create a data warehouse in Greenplum thus I want to give primary key constraint, How I should go ahead to define constraint

Comment: How do you define a primary key constraint?  alter table test add primary key (a);  But you original question is about how to update.  You can't update the distribution column so pick a different column to distribute by or don't update that column.

Comment: You can update a "DISTRIBUTED BY" column with PQO optimizer. If you enable that then you will not see this error. You can enable it by using SET OPTIMIZER=ON;. It will enable PQO at session level.

Answer (score 0):

Although Anuraag has answered your question but there is also an alternate way to update your table

First change your distributed clause
Alter table table name set distributed randomly.

Second , run your update script

Third, reset your distributed clause
Alter table table name set distributed by (a).

Reshuffle your records across your segments
Alter table table name set ( with reorganize=true).